# VueJS watch или computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Выручайте, в край запутался. Есть компонент вида

```
Vue.component('News', {
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: function() {
                return [];
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getNews() {
            axios.get('/backend/news/item')
                .then((response) => {
                    return this.items = response.data.News.items;
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err.status);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

При вызове метода getNews() как отследить что свойство items изменилось ? Что нужно использовать в данном случае watch или computed ?

Comment: Так как вы делаете - делать нельзя. Нельзя менять пропсы. Их можно менять только в родительском компоненте и следить в дочернем.
Если уж у вас `items` передаются из родителя, то почему вы вызываете `get('/backend/news/item')` не там же?

Comment: В каком смысле ? Это по сути и есть родительский компонент, выше только инициализация Vue происходит, т.е. так получается `const app = new Vue({
    data: {
        components: [] // здесь как раз и будет News
    }
}`

Comment: _следить в дочернем_ Каким образом ? Дайте пример пожалуйста, я делал вроде этого `computed: {
        items: function() {
            return this.items;
        }
    },`

Comment: Но получил ошибку - items и items одинаковое название, а если названия разные сделать, как отслеживать не пойму...

Comment: > Это по сути и есть родительский компонент

Но вы определяете в нем **props**. Неувязочка.

> Но получил ошибку - items и items одинаковое название

Само собой. А как Vue должен проп от компьютеда отличать? Сделайте **computedItems** и им уже пользуйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, до меня дошло вроде - пропсы можно задавать только в дочернем компоненте, иначе использовать data, правильно ? Просто если компонент родительский как в него передать данные извне не совсем понятно..._Сделайте computedItems_ - тогда он не видит изменений в items :(

Comment: Сделайте демо работающее минимально. Я вам покажу как надо строить иерархию.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю причем здесь иерархия. Задача вроде бы тривиальна в теории - отследить изменение в items, если items === 0 кнопку удаляем, если > 0 добавляем. Но на деле что watch, что computed у меня работает не так как дожлно работать... Для отрисовки я использую createElement()

Comment: У вас компонент `News` в какой компонент вложен? Вот там и обновляйте `items`, который прокинут пропсом. Ну или остается делать `$emit` в родителя.
Вы же понимаете, что не работает `watch` из-за вас, а не сам по себе?
Ну и сделайте демо наконец, чтобы наглядно показать что не так. Либо перечитайте документацию. У вас пробел в знаниях основ Vue.

Comment: watch работает, но не совсем корректно. Я понимаю что мой косяк. Но я только учусь, так что мне простительно. Не знаю правильно или нет, запихнул все render() Демку могу сделать, просто там куча всего, помимо этого, а News я как пример привел, хотя суть та же.

Comment: _У вас компонент News в какой компонент вложен?_ Выше только сам Vue уже идет `const app = new Vue(тут я и дергаю компоненты)`